# database design and EF model with various User Roles

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4

I need some guidance for a database design around a project management system.  My question is mainly around how should I design the columns or tables for functionality around the various Roles.

The system will have several users in a Users table and the following roles in Roles table
**(Company Adminis, Project Manager, Supervisor, Alternate Supervisor, Employee)**

The various entities involved are Users, Roles, UserRoleMapping, Company, Projects

- A company has many Projects and has one ore more Company Administrators
- Every Project has a Project Manager
- Every Project has several Employees assigned to it
- Each Employee has a Supervisor

I am looking for a good db design that would translate well to an Entity Framework model.

This is the approach I have thought of and would appreciate any feedback:
Use default ASP.NET Membership that would provide Users, Roles, UserRoleMapping functionality.

Then, using the base Users table from Membership and creating Role specific tables to store various users: Employees, CompanyAdmins, Supervisors

**UPDATE TWO: Please see the new image below.  Thinking of using a Table per Hierarchy to store the various managers (Company Admins for a company, Project Manager for a project, Supervisor for an employee) in the same table. 
What do you think of this as the database design and please suggest how this would work for the Entity Model?**

[image]

Also, on another note - do you think the way I have connected Project, Tasks and Employees is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: How will you constrain `EmployeeTask` to `Employees` from the same company as the `Task`? Same with `USerProjects`?

Comment: hmmm, not sure. Could I add CompanyID to these tables as well or rely on the model or application logic to not allow such?  Please advise.

Comment: Damir, see my update in the question above.  What do you think of this?

Comment: From your model, what logic do you follow to have two separated entities "Users" and "Employees"? I suspect "Users" don't need to be "Employees" of a company, and they could be, for instance, internal admins or auditors, and the "Users" entity is a parent entity of other types of entities that represent a particular type of actor in the system. If this is correct, should "Roles" apply to "Users" in general for this particular case, or just to "Employees"? Do you mean to manage the roles for "Employees" or for the ensemble of "Users"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big could the employee table get?  In their role as administrator, supervisor or manager, all of those are employees (they may or may not have a supervisor though).  Can an employee be assigned to several projects?  Can an employee be assigned multiple projects? In my case, an employ could be assigned to only one project at a time (or in the case of certain employees, none).  This allowed me to modify a basic employee object like so:
EmpID
[Employee info]
SupervisorID (can be null and is an employee_id)
AlternateSupervisorID (can be null and is an employee_id)|Project_ID (can be null) and is a FK

only other object is project with a PK of project_id.

Comment: Glen, I really like your approach. Employee table (now renamed to AllUsers will have maybe 2000 records or less). Employee can be assigned to multiple projects. I have updated my question with a revised design. I would appreciate your comments on how the model classes should look like.

Comment: The reason I asked is that self-referencing FK could be a performance issue on large tables but even 20-30K shouldn't be an issue. Does a UsersCompany.companyID have to exist in Company and UserProjects.ProjectID have to exist in Projects?  You'd want to document that.  It also looks like those objects exist to improve retrieval of certain information.

Comment: Glen. I just updated the diagram in my original question. Could you please review?

Comment: Sorry took me so long.  Didn't realize you were talking about multiple companies but it looks like it'll work.  Don't think you'll need the relationship between tasks and employees but that relationship may help with scalability.  Don't think I'd hang roles as relating to users since that table is very close to the name of a table owned by the DBMS.